# GNOME shell doesn't detect custom .desktop file

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop

According to [official guide](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en), gnome launcher supports to see and display custom `.desktop` file in these two paths:
`/usr/share/applications`
`~/.local/share/applications`

But no path above works. I even restart OS but nothing change. I also try to `locate` some sample `.desktop` in gnome launcher including built-in apps and new apps (openToonz). Here is a path I have found:
`/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`

Apparently, I copy my `.desktop` to the path above and waiting... in void.

What did I do wrong? Below is the content inside my `.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OALD
Comment=Open OALD online in Firefox
Exec=firefox "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com"
Icon=oald.png
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Education; Network; Dictionary;
Keywords=dictionary;internet;web app;
Actions=private-mode


[Desktop Action private-mode]
Name=Open in Private Mode
Exec=firefox -private-window "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com"
```

Btw, my `.desktop` is a link opened by Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your `.desktop` file is the following line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

`NoDisplay=true` [means](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys)

> this application exists, but don't display it in the menus.

So either remove this line or change it to

```
NoDisplay=false
```

Then put the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` (only for the current user) or in `/usr/share/applications` (for all users).